# How do I join numpy references?

Tags: python, numpy

I find myself often using SoA for speed but I'd like to be able to reference them as just an array. If I can select the slice of all of an element, as  `nda[:]['a'][:]` does for `a`, is there a way to construct a flat reference to all of these items?

```
import numpy as np

WARP_SIZE = 4

dt = np.dtype([('a', (np.float64, WARP_SIZE)),  ('b', (np.float64, WARP_SIZE))])
nda = np.ndarray(3, dtype=dt)
nda[:] = 0
a_vals = nda[:]['a'][:]
a_vals[0:2] = 3
print(nda)
nda[:] = 0
a_vals.flatten()[0:2] = 3
print(nda)
```

Comment: What does SoA mean in this context?

Comment: Also what is a "flat reference"?

Comment: SoA = Structure of Arrays. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA and by flat I mean reshaping the reference of `array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],[0., 0., 0., 0.],[0., 0., 0., 0.]])` to a flat vec of 12.

Comment: Obligatory silly question: do you really need structured arrays? Can't you just use columns/slices of a multidimensional array?

Comment: I haven't seen this syntax where the structured dtype tuples contain tuples inside, so I presume this is why you need recarrays.

Comment: @andrasdeak these eventually go on CUDA in my use case where layout really matters.

Comment: Can you clarify your desired output? It seems you have a AoSoA (``dt`` marks an SoA, ``nda`` is an array of ``dt``s), not a SoA, so the description is a bit off. *What* do you want to reference as an array? Do you want the equivalent of ``nda['a']`` (an array of arrays) as a single flat array?

Comment: yes. I'd like to edit all the `['a']`s in a single vector.

Comment: Do you want a view that pretends the ``'a'``s are consecutive, or a copy that aligns them consecutively?

Comment: the former. This is for the internal binding layer.

Comment: Structured arrays link: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: The problem isn't with the use of structured array.  It's that `flatten()` is always a copy.  Use  `ravel()` or `flat`.  And for create `nda` I'd use `np.zeros(3, dtype=dt)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on your problem:

```py
a_vals = nda['a']  # should be the same as yours
a_vals_flat = a_vals.reshape(-1)  # flattened a_vals
a_vals_flat.base is a_vals  # False!
```

So you can get a view into the fields labelled by `'a'` with `nda['a']`, this is fine. However when you flatten this array you no longer get a view into your previous array. This is probably because the array is not contiguous:

```
>>> a_vals.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

We can reproduce this behaviour with a non-contiguous view of a regular array:

```py
arr = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(3, 2, 4)[:, 0, :]  # shape (3, 4)
arr_flat = arr.reshape(-1)
print(arr_flat.base is arr)  # False

arr_flat[:] = -1

print(arr)
# [[ 0  1  2  3]
#  [ 8  9 10 11]
#  [16 17 18 19]]
```

What you *can* do instead is use the `.flat` `flatiter` attribute. I have vague memories of this potentially leading to problems, so handle with care. But it seems to work:

```
import numpy as np 
 
WARP_SIZE = 4 
 
dt = np.dtype([('a', (np.float64, WARP_SIZE)),  ('b', (np.float64, WARP_SIZE))])
nda = np.zeros(3, dtype=dt) 
a_vals = nda['a'] 
a_vals_flat = a_vals.flat 
nda[:] = 0 
a_vals_flat[0:2] = 3 
print(nda)      
# [([3., 3., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0.]) ([0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0.])
#  ([0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0.])]
```

Comment: Oh sweet, that's awesome, very nifty.